# Corretor ortográfico deixou de funcionar nas caixas de resposta e comentários

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro

Após a graduação, com a alteração para o novo *layout*, notei que o corretor ortográfico, nas caixas de reposta e comentário, deixou de funcionar.

É um problema só meu ou é um *bug* do novo *layout*?

Comment: Utiliza qual navegador? [Aqui, no Firefox, está funcionando normalmente](http://i.imgur.com/k4l5vsv.jpg)

Comment: Utilizo o Firefox, e já verifiquei se tinha a opção "Verificar a ortografia" *checked*

Comment: Peço desculpa. Já encontrei a causa, como disse no comentário anterior tenho a opção "Verificar a ortografia" *checked* mas em "Idiomas" nenhuma estava selecionada. Não percebo como aconteceu já que é *RadioButton".